# Java: How can I check is file correct MS Word document?

Tags: java, ms-word

How can I check is file correct MS Word document by using Java?
The main purpose is filter files that will be opened by MS Word with any mistake

Comment: What is the API used for editing the file?  Apache POI is a good one. Even then to really verify it can be opened in MSWord, you should open the document in that tool.

Answer (score 1):

Try [a Java API for MS Office Docs](http://poi.apache.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Apache POI is a great project for reading and writing MS Word docs from Java. However, it is not MS Word. So whilst it can open a lot of Word documents, there will always be a margin for error. ie. Documents that it considers ok, but have problems when opened by Word. The only program that can accurately open and check a Word document is Word itself.

So you need to consider what you mean by opening "without any mistake". What are you actually trying to validate? and perhaps - do you really need to do this at all?

Comment: I need to print an uploaded ms word document to pdf printer in server mode (convert form word to pdf). So I need to save myself from any problems in this process